# How does MySQL handle huge databases?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

For the sake of example:

Let's say my database has 1 table where the fields are

**id, first_name (VARCHAR 100 chars), last_name (VARCHAR 100 chars), about (VARCHAR 10,000 chars)**

Now let's say the database is 100 Gigs large.

How will random access look like on a machine that only has 4 Gigs of RAM?

Will the query take constant time every time it's made?

Comment: Depends on the select query and the indexes.

Comment: id is the primary index. And let's say you want to select FROM table WHERE last_name  = '... ~100 chars ...';

Comment: That would take a while. Using an index on last_name would make it really fast.

Comment: Can you index both id and last_name? And if so, how does that affect the RAM of the machine it's running on?

Comment: You can index all columns you want. I think MySQL will grab more memory to hold the index there.

Comment: Yes you can. Indexes are not always stored in memory they are physical structures on disk that are optimised for reading/selecting data.

Comment: Proper indexing and it has been used in queries which makes query execution faster also make sure that optimized datatype has been used.

Answer (score 1):

If you search on first name and it is not indexed the server will read each row in the table and compare it to the where clause. This query will probably vary hugely in time since the time taken to retrieve the result is dependant on the position of the row. For example firstname 'a' will be quick to find and firstname 'z' will take much longer. Essentially you are doing a linear/sequential access of the database.

If there was a index on the firstname MySQL build a tree on the column. Trees are highly efficient when used in searching. Basically find values 'a' and 'z' should take the same amount of operations since you are doing a binary search. Note that I am saying operations.

There is now way you can gaurantee that a query will always execute in the same amount of time. Just remember while a database is memory intensive most people overlook the fact that a database is really bound to disk io. These factors make it highly unlikely that you can gaurantee execution time is always predictable and constant. However you can ensure that the number of operations used remain optimised.

Just one other thing while indexes speeds up reads they slow down writes. So indexing is a double edged sword. Index only what you reallly need to.